# How to design and Build microservices in an AWS serverless architecture?

Tags: aws-lambda, microservices, serverless

I'm totally new to the concept of microservices and AWS serverless architecture. I Have a project that I have to divide it into microservices that should run on `AWS Lambda` but I face a difficulty on how to design it.

When searching I could not find a usefull documentation about how to divide and design microservices, all the docs I saw comparing monolithic app to microservices app or deploying microservice on aws lambda.

In my case I have to develop an ERP (Entreprise Resource Planning) that have to manage clients, manage stocks, manage books, manage commands..  so should I make a service for clients and a service for books... and then if I notice a lot of dependency between two microservices then I make them one ??
And for the DB, is it good to use one DB ( dynamoDB) for all microservices instead of a DB for every service in this case (ERP)?

Any help is really appreciated.
If anybody has a usefull document that can help me, I will be very thakfull.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think the architecture of your data and services can depend on a few things:

1. Which data sources are used/available
2. What your requirements/desired functionalities are
3. Business logic or any other restrictions/concerns

In order to reduce the size of a service, we want to limit the reasons why an application or another service would access that service to as few as possible. This reduces the amount of overall maintenance for managing it and also gives you a lot of flexibility when using their deployments.

**For example:** A service which transforms data from multiple sources and makes it available via API can split into an API using data processing service with a new, cleaner data source. This would prevent overreliance on large, older services and data, and make integration of that newer, smaller service easier for your applications.

In your scenario, you may get away with having services for managing clients, books, and stocks separately, but it also depends on how your data sources are integrated as well as what services are already available to you. You may want to create other microservices or databases to help reduce the size and organize the data into the format you want.

Depending on your business needs, combining or keeping separate two microservices can depend on different things too. Does one of these services have the potential to be useful for other applications? Is it dedicated to a specific project? Keeping services separate, small, and focused gives you room to expand or shrink things if needed. The same goes for data sources.

There are always many ways to approach it. Consider what *your* needs/problems are first before opting with a certain tool for creating solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Microservices**

It's simply small services running that can be scaled and deployed
independently.

**AWS Serveless**

Every application is different so you may not find single architecture that fits every application. Generally a simplge Serverless application consists of Lambda Function , Api Gateway , DB (SQL/NoSQL) . Serverless is great cloud native choice and you get availability , scalability out of box and you would be very quick to deploy your stuff.

**How to design Serverless Application**

There is no right answer. You need to architect your system in a way that individual microservices can work cohesively. in your case books, Stocks need to be separate microserivces which means they are separate Lambda functions. For DB , Dynamo is good and powerful choice as long as you know how NoSQL works and caveats around it. you need to think before hand what are challenges around NoSQL and how you would partition data ? What if you need to use the complex reporting and would NoSQL be good choice ? There are patterns around to get away that issue. Since Dynamo DB operate on table level so each microservice will preferably be separate table that can be scaled independently and makes more sense.

**What's the right architecture for my application?**

Instead of looking for one right answer i would strongly suggest to read individual component before making your mind. There are tons of articles and blogs. If i was you i would look in the following order

- Microservices - why we need then ?
- Serverless - In General
- Event Driven architecture
- SQL vs NoSQL
- Lambda and DynamoDB and how they actually work
- DevOps and how that would work in serverless
- Patterns

Once you have bit of understanding you would be in way better position to decide what suits you best.